# emergency and/or 7700 squawk database or API?

Tags: emergency

Is there an API or some database somewhere of aircraft that have squawked 7700 (emergency).  Where do mobile apps like FlightRadar24 get their notifications form?

I'd like to monitor when flight to/from/diverted to my local airport are involved in emergencies.

Comment: 2 problems here. 1) 7700 DB is worlwide, USA, europe, asia or what. 2 second question is another question and is a duplicate. You can get that answer from 'help' section in FlightRadar24 app.

Comment: Are you looking to track emergencies or just 7700 squawks?  (If you are talking to ATC and have an emergency you'll just tell them, you wont squawk 7700)

Comment: Any flight emergency would be useful to track.  Ultimately I'd like to know when a originating from, arriving at, or diverting to my local airport is involved in an emergency

Comment: Flight radar etc directly track ADS-B (as in they have a network of receivers on the ground) or the FAA feed